# string comparison not working with sqlplus output

Tags: shell-script, test, sqlplus

Code:

```
iIMSI=`sqlplus -s ${APP_ORA_USER}/${APP_ORA_PASS}@${APP_DB_INST} << EOF
SET HEAD OFF PAGESIZE 0 LINESIZE 1000 TRIMOUT ON TIMING OFF
select resource_value from agd1_resources where resource_type='3'
and subscriber_id in (select subscriber_id from agd1_resources where resource_value='$sSUBSCRIBER');
exit;
EOF`

if [ "$iIMSI" = "no rows selected" ]; then
echo hello
else echo elseblock
fi
```

Question:

I'm giving `sSUBSCRIBER` value which is not present in table, so the query result is 'no rows selected' which I stored in iIMSI.

Why is my *if condition* is not working (it is always running the else block)?

Comment: Is that text _actually_ stored in the variable, or is it printed to the terminal?

Comment: What does `printf '%s\n' "$iIMSI" | sed -n l` output?

Answer (score 0):

To check, if you have the expected value in the variable, please insert an `echo "$iIMSI"` in the line above the if-statement.

I tried the following script

```
$ cat test.sh
#!/bin/bash

iIMSI="no rows selected"
if [ "$iIMSI" = "no rows selected" ]; then
echo hello
else echo elseblock
fi
```

and it worked as expected.

```
$ ./test.sh 
hello
```